# Twig: Working internationalization (i18n) example

Tags: php, internationalization, twig

I am looking for a working i18n example for Twig (the template engine).

Documentation is a bit sparse when it comes to language files. Where should they go, how should they look and what should they be named? I have been trying with .po/.mo files, no luck.

If someone could point me in the right direction...

See: [the i18n extension example](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html) which does not really tell me much about the language files themselves.

Note: I want to use Twig on its own, not as part of Symfony.

Here is my php-file:

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$vars = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $vars[$key] = json_decode(utf8_encode(urldecode($value)));
}

/* Prepare Twig template enginge */
require_once './lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    //'cache' => './cache',
    'cache' => false
));

/* i18n */
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());

$availableLanguages = array(
    'en' => 'en_EN',
    'de' => 'de_DE',
    'default' => 'de_DE'
);

// Set language
$locale = array_key_exists($_GET['lang'], $availableLanguages) ? $availableLanguages[$_GET['lang']] : $availableLanguages['default'];
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

// Specify the location of the translation tables
bindtextdomain('kalkulator', 'includes/locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset('kalkulator', 'UTF-8');

// Choose domain
textdomain('kalkulator');

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('print.tpl');

$html = $template->render($vars);

switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'mail':

    break;
    default:
        echo $html;
    break;
}


?>
```

And inside includes/locale I have the following files:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user group  670 Jul 28 10:17 kalkulator-de_DE.mo
-rw-r--r--  1 user group  982 Jul 28 10:22 kalkulator-de_DE.po
-rw-r--r--  1 user group  688 Jul 28 10:38 kalkulator-en_EN.mo
-rw-r--r--  1 user group 1004 Jul 28 10:38 kalkulator-en_EN.po
```

And inside the print.tpl file I am using tags to specify which parts are to be translated:

```
{% trans %}
Text to be translated
{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: Twig is a template engine. What do you expect for internationalization? That it can handle french templates? And cuban ones? I bet it can ;) - so please share what you're looking for.

Comment: See my modified answer. Twig has a i18n extension that works with gettext.

Comment: you can use [this extension](https://github.com/smmoosavi/twig-php-gettext). this extension is pure php and system-gettext independent.

Answer (score 2):

The twig i18n extension is based on gettext. So first of all everything related to gettext applies. You find that documented here: [Gettext <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/gettext).

So now to the more concrete parts of you question, but please ensure you've at least understood the basic principles with gettext:

> Where should they [the language files] go

Into the directory that has been registered for the **text-domain**.

> , how should they look and what should they be named?

Language files should be named the following:

*text-domain*`-`*locale*`.po/mo`

Example for a text domain called `myAppPhp` and the `fr_FR` locale:

```
myAppPhp-fr_FR.po
myAppPhp-fr_FR.mo
```

> I have been trying with `.po/.mo` files, no luck.

`.po/.mo` sounds good to me, maybe you have just missed the path where to move them or you have forgotten to add the text-domain in front.

Comment: hakre, thank you for your input. I have edited my question to reflect what I have already done (should have done that from the start). I don't see where I am doing anything wrong. I use an additional autocache.php file to cache the Twig output, which allows me to use xgettext on the generated php files in order to create the po/mo files.

Comment: @Joseph: Check the return value from `bindtextdomain` if it's the full path of the directory you're expecting.

Comment: Turns out I had used en_EN as a locale. That did not work. I changed it to en_GB and renamed the folder. Now it works, but I am not sure whether it was actually a caching problem, or if you really have to provide a valid locale, and en_EN is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything possible in slim 3 but nothing was working, only slim 2, so I've created my own way. Basically the system detects the language from the browser and load the correct translation file, more details in the picture:

[image: my way to solve]