# Issues with twig and internationalization

Tags: php, internationalization, twig

I'm developping a web app using the twing template engine and i have some issues with the internatiolization.

I've installed the i18n twig extension.

It seems that my application can't find the correct .mo files.

PS: I don't work with symfony

Here's my project structure (Only the folder related to this problem)

```
-Project
--application
----base
------controllers
--------BaseControl.php
--locale
----en_CA
------LC_MESSAGES
--------messages.mo
--------messages.po
--index.php
```

Here is the code that seem to not work

```
// Set Twig master template environment
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(APP . '/../assets/templates/');

// Create twig environment
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader , array(
    'debug'            => ENV['debug_mode'],
    //'strict_variables' => ENV['debug_mode'],
    'charset'          => strtoupper(CHARSET)
 )); 

 // Set i18n extension to twig
 $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());

 // Set language for i18n extension
 putenv('LC_ALL='.APP_LANG[LANGUAGE]); // en_CA
 setlocale(LC_ALL, APP_LANG[LANGUAGE]); // en_CA

 // Set domaine name
 $domain = 'messages';

 // Specify the location of the translation tables
 bindtextdomain($domain, ROOT . '/locale');
 bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, strtoupper(CHARSET));

 // Choose domain
 textdomain($domain);

 // Return twig object with settings
 return $twig;
```

Comment: That is how I solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861546/twig-working-internationalization-i18n-example/47641059#47641059